# Max weighted matching where edge weight depends on the matching

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, matching-theory

Given a bipartite graph $G$, we seek a maximal weighted matching $E$. The particularity is below. Once an edge $e$ is chosen, the action of choosing $e$ adds a negative weight $w(e,e')$ to any other edge $e'$ in $M$. That is, the edge weight depends on the matching we choose. How to approach this problem? Clearly when $w(e,e')=0$ for any pair of $(e,e')$, the problem degenerates to standard max weight matching.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the weight assigned to matching M is sum_{e in M} (sum_{e' in M} w(e,e'))?

Comment: Thank you Louigi. Yes, we can formulate in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Let binary variable $x_e$ indicate whether $e\in M$.  The usual maximum weighted matching problem is to maximize $\sum_e c_e x_e$ subject to:
$$\sum_{e\in E: v\in e} x_e \le 1 \quad \text{for all $v\in V$}$$

To model your variant, introduce nonnegative variable $y_{e,e'}$ for each pair $e<e'$ of edges, change the objective to maximize $\sum_e c_e x_e + \sum_{e<e'} w(e,e')y_{e,e'}$, and impose constraints:
$$x_e + x_{e'} - 1 \le y_{e,e'}$$
Note that $y_{e,e'}$ will automatically be integer-valued even without explicitly defining it to be binary.

Comment: Thank you Rob. Let me be more specific. I seek answers or references to the following questions: (1) is my problem NP-hard? (2) how to design polynomial algorithm or approximate algorithm with constant factor to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by *maximal* we actually mean *maximum*.

A *rainbow perfect matching* in a (not necessarily proper) edge-colored bipartite graph $G$ on $2n$ vertices is a perfect matching of $G$ such that no two edges have the same color.

Let $G = (V,E)$ be an edge-colored bipartite graph on $2n$ vertices. Let $w(\cdot)$ be the all-ones function, and define $w(\cdot,\cdot)$ such that $w(e,e') = 0$ if $e,e' \in E$ are a pair of disjoint edges that have different colors; otherwise, $w(e,e') = -c$ for any $c > 0$. An algorithm that solves your problem outputs $n$ if and only if $G$ has a rainbow perfect matching.

The rainbow perfect matching problem for bipartite graphs is NP-Complete (see, for  example, Theorem 1 in 
Van Bang Le, Florian Pfender,
*Complexity results for rainbow matchings*,
Theoretical Computer Science,
Volume 524,
2014).

I don't have a hardness of approximation proof, but I am skeptical that your problem admits a polynomial-time constant-factor approximation algorithm. It seems very close to the quadratic assignment problem, and such problems are hard to approximate in polynomial time within a constant factor in both theory and practice.